# Error:(12, 21) String types not allowed (at 'android:layout_height' with value ''). with 3dp

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

I defined `<item name="android:layout_height">3dp</item>` as an item im my custom style.
But I got the following error messages:

> Error:(12, 21) String types not allowed (at 'android:layout_height' with value '').
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/juude/prog/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I think it maybe the android studio problem, because I did not encounter this problem in previous builds. And I did not change this style since.
But I cannot see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, you can not define a dimen bigger than 0 in Style definition.Instead I defined the dimen as
`<dimen name="the_height">50dp</dimen>`
and then make a reference like 
`<item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/the_height</item>`